# Using a NamedQuery with a composite class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following class defined in my mapping XML file:

```
<class name="com.data.StateRefData" table="STATE_REF">
   <composite-id name="primaryKey" class="com.data.StateRefPkData">
       <key-property name="countryCode">
           <column name="COUNTRY_CODE"  />
        </key-property>

        <key-property name="state">
            <column name="STATE"  />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>

   <property name="dialingCode" column="DIALING_CODE"></property>
   <property name="isActive" column="IS_ACTIVE"></property>
   <property name="localeCode" column="LOCALE_CODE"></property>
   <property name="stName" column="ST_NAME"></property>
</class>
```

I am trying to define a NameQuery for this class. What I tried was:

```
<query name="findState">
    <![CDATA[ from
      com.data.StateRefData
        WHERE primaryKey = :primaryKey
    ]]>
 </query>
```

The Java code that I use to call this is:

```
Query stateQuery = null;
List<StateRefData> stateList = null;
StateRefPkData primaryKey = new StateRefPkData();
StateRefData filter = new StateRefData();

primaryKey.setCountryCode(inCountryCode);
primaryKey.setState(inStateProvince);
filter.setPrimaryKey(primaryKey);

stateQuery = session.getNamedQuery("findState");
stateQuery.setProperties(filter);
```

However, I get these errors right at the "stateQuery.list()" part:

```
[ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72] Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ','.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:59)
   at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1596)
   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1577)
   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:395)
   at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:844)
   at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
```

Any idea on how to use a NamedQuery with a composite?

**Note:** I have also tried doing:

```
stateQuery.setParameter("primaryKey", primaryKey);
```

and it still has the error.

**New (edited):**
Here is the HQL and SQL that happens when I execute the code:

```
[DEBUG AST:223] --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  \-[FROM] 'from'
    |     \-[RANGE] 'RANGE'
    |        +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] 'com'
    |        |  |  \-[IDENT] 'data'
    |        |  \-[IDENT] 'StateRefData'
    |        \-[ALIAS] 'd'
    \-[WHERE] 'WHERE'
       \-[EQ] '='
          +-[DOT] '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] 'd'
          |  \-[IDENT] 'primaryKey'
          \-[COLON] ':'
             \-[IDENT] 'primaryKey'

[DEBUG AST:193] --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (STATE_REF)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{derived select clause}'
    |  +-[SELECT_EXPR] SelectExpressionImpl: 'statere0_.COUNTRY_CODE as COUNTRY1_, statere0_.STATE as STATE' {FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=d,role=null,tableName=STATE_REF,tableAlias=statere0_,colums={,className=com.data.StateRefData}}}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'statere0_.DIALING_CODE as DIALING3_60_, statere0_.IS_ACTIVE as IS4_60_, statere0_.LOCALE_CODE as LOCALE5_60_, statere0_.ST_NAME as ST6_60_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[d], fromElementByTableAlias=[statere0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'STATE_REF statere0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=d,role=null,tableName=STATE_REF,tableAlias=statere0_,colums={,className=com.data.StateRefData}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'WHERE'
       \-[EQ] SqlNode: '='
          +-[DOT] DotNode: '(statere0_.COUNTRY_CODE, statere0_.STATE)' {propertyName=primaryKey,dereferenceType=2,propertyPath=primaryKey,path=d.primaryKey,tableAlias=statere0_,className=com.data.StateRefData,classAlias=d}
          |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: '(statere0_.COUNTRY_CODE, statere0_.STATE)' {alias=d, className=com.data.StateRefData, tableAlias=statere0_}
          |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'primaryKey' {originalText=primaryKey}
          \-[NAMED_PARAM] SqlNode: '?'
```

Comment: Could you set the debugging level of sql statements to DEBUG like explained here: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html

From the log it's obvious that the query was constructed. If you had known how it looks it could be easier to realize what went wrong

Comment: @Boris - I have viewed the HQL and SQL statements produced. They still do not show much in there to help.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Also for future reference, the SQL query without the BNF (the things between the [ squre brackets ] ) should be printed further down in the logs.  It is hard to read and determine the true SQL being ran against the database when it is displayed in the "tree" format above.

Comment: @matt: Sorry, but that is how log4j displayed it. So I just copy/pasted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide the SQL code that is being generated by turning on SQL logging?

Here is a sample if you were using log4j.properties:

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

**UPDATE #1**

I am not sure why the existing query does not work, but you should also give this a try.  No need to update any other code as passing a POJO should automatically bind the getters to the named parameters.

```
<query name="findState">
    <![CDATA[ from
      com.data.StateRefData
        WHERE primaryKey.countryCode = :countryCode AND primaryKey.state = :state
    ]]>
</query>
```

Comment: @matt: I will try this out today and let you know how this works. Thanks!

Comment: I did have to change the Java code some. Instead of filter.setProperty(), I removed filter and did "stateQuery.setProperties(primaryKey)". Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that inCountryCode or inStateProvince is empty or null?

Comment: No there is not. I always make sure there is a value here. I also double checked this using Eclipse Debugger.